# HTML5 Input tag capture camera on iPad

Tags: html, ipad, ios7

I am developing an application and one requirement is that the user can take a new photo from camera or select existing photo from gallery. I am using this HTML5 tag:

`<input id="a-imagery-image" type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera" style="display:none" multiple>`

When I run the application in iPad, it's only giving the option to select from gallery, not showing options like "take photo", "choose existing", "cancel".
I have tried in both chrome and safari.

> iPad Details:
>   version: 7.0.2(11A501)
>   Model: MD371LL/A

Could you please help me with this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you publish your code?

Comment: i have updated the code. <input id="a-imagery-image" type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera" style="display:none" multiple>

Answer (score 3):

I encounter issues by using a combination of the tag "multiple" with capture="camera".

Try it without using multiple.

Answer (score 0):

Write like this

```
<input id="test" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" style="display:none" multiple>
```

BUT,on my test, it only support on IOS9+.

Answer (score -1):

try remove `capture=camera` i think this will work.